# Does using `getInitialProps ` in custom _app component in next.js disable client-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, server-side, client-side, next.js, server-side-rendering

According to next.js official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-app):

```
import React from 'react'
import App from 'next/app'

class MyApp extends App {
  // Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
  // every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
  // perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
  // be server-side rendered.
  //
  // static async getInitialProps(appContext) {
  //   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  //   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  //
  //   return { ...appProps }
  // }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

As far as I understand if I use `getInitialProps` in my `_app.js` file this will cause my pages to be server-side rendered. But does this mean that client-side rendering will not work (navigation etc.)? If not what exactly is meant by

> causing every page in your app to be server-side rendered.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not got it correctly, only [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs#automatic-static-optimization) will be disabled, cause if you are using `getInitailProps` that means the page is not static (requires additional data from the server in order to render), so Next can't generate a static **html file** for it.

Comment: The link to Automatic Static Optimization is now available [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization).